# using the TOP statement for updating data in sqlite with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I don't know if the answer has been given already, but I couldn't find it. I am trying to update data in an existing table in sqlite with python. The data has to come in rows were other data is already saved in. My code looks like this:

```
for lst in adresCor:
    cursor.execute('''INSERT TOP 11 INTO Huisartsen(lat, long)
                  VALUES(?,?)''', (lst[0], lst[1]))
```

And I get the following error: OperationalError: near "TOP": syntax error

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Comment: Remove `top 11`. If you want the data sorted in any way you do that in your selects when you retrieve the data

Comment: But I don't want to select any data, I want to add data. Do you know then how i should do that?

Comment: Insert adds data https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: I know that, but when I use it with TOP, like I said in my question, I get an error...

Comment: Because TOP is not legal syntax in sqlite.  Check the railroad chart on the link I commented on above

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do  you think the TOP 11 would do there?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't see the link, thanks. But how do I specify the rows I want the data to then?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I think the TOP 11 makes sure that the data is added to the first 11 rows of my table (I hope it does)

Comment: Databases have no concept of row order. They are only ordered when you select data from there.

Comment: Do you want to INSERT new rows or do you want to UPDATE existing rows? It is obvious that you have very little knowledge of databases. You should really really take a tutorial first

Comment: I took a tutorial but it was a while ago, i'm sorry. You are right, I want to update rows, in this case the first 11. But how can I state that if a database doesn't have a row order

Comment: I used UPDATE instead of INSERT because now.. This is what I have: `for lst in adresCor:
    cursor.execute('''UPDATE TOP (11) Huisartsen(lat, long)
                  VALUES(?,?)''', (lst[0], lst[1]))` Now I get the following response: OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Why do you keep using TOP.  TOP does not exist in sqlite syntax.

Comment: Because so far, I don't know what to use instead..

Comment: Read my answer.  Try it out.  Do you know what a primary key is?  Can you show the table schema?

Comment: Yes, I know what a primary key is and I have them in my table. But I think there are 2 problems: 1) the primary keys aren't succesive 2) the list with data I want to add doesn't contain the primary keys

Comment: Then there is no way to replace the first 11 rows, since the rows are not ordered.  A relational database is ***relational***. This means you select rows by the values in their columns.  What you are asking makes no sense

Comment: Sorry for bothering you in that case.

Comment: @joelgoldstick I figured out a way to add the primary key to my data and combined it with your answer, so it works! Thanks for the help and sorry that it was not very clear what I was trying to do.

Comment: Good.  Glad you solved your problem.  Why not post your answer so others might learn how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update, and assuming you have a primary key called id, and it is an auto-increment field you can do this:

```
for id, lst in enumerate(adresCor):
    sql = "update Huisartsen set lat = %f, long = %f where id = %d" % (lst[0], lst[1], id)
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

for data like this:

```
lst = [1233.44, 44.3]
id  = 1

>>> sql
'update Huisartsen set lat = 1233.440000, long = 44.300000 where id = 1'
```